# Algorithm to extract edge list efficiently from a vector

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

I have a long list (~10 million elements) and the elements that have repeated values are pairs. I want to extract the list of pairs from the list, e.g.

```
R = [1,3,1,6,9,6,1,2,3,0]
```

will spit out list of pairs

```
P = [[e1,e3],[e1,e7],[e3,e7],[e4,e6],[e2,e9]]
```

What is the efficient algorithm to achieve this for a long list?

Comment: If you really need the performance, you should consider doing this in C and make an interface for it. It would also help if you would describe the algorithm a bit more

Comment: How many duplicate numbers in this list do you have? You're listing all pairs of duplicates of a certain number: if there are many duplicates, the list of pairs could grow very, very large...

Comment: Can you please explain what is that you want to solve. Processing a list of 10 million elements with an O(n^2) algorithm smells to be a X-Y problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group the indices together based on value, then iterate through pairs of indices using `combinations`.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import combinations

R = [1,3,1,6,9,6,1,2,3,0]
d = defaultdict(list)
for idx,item in enumerate(R,1):
    d[item].append(idx)

result = []
for indices in d.itervalues():
    result.extend(combinations(indices, 2))

print result
```

Result:

```
[(1, 3), (1, 7), (3, 7), (2, 9), (4, 6)]
```

Populating the defaultdict takes O(len(R)) time on average. Finding combinations is O(N!) time, where N is the number of indices in the largest group.

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to do a pass over the list to find the elements with the same value and store them into new lists, then find the elements that appear more than once and collect the combinations:

```
In [18]: from collections import defaultdict

In [19]: d = defaultdict(list)

In [20]: for i, e in enumerate(R, 1):
   ....:     d[e].append(i)
   ....:

In [21]: from itertools import combinations

In [22]: from itertools import chain

In [23]: list(chain(*[list(combinations(v,2)) for v in d.values() if len(v) > 1]))
Out[23]: [(1, 3), (1, 7), (3, 7), (2, 9), (4, 6)]
```

Answer (score 0):

My simple solution:

```
def extract(edges):
    dic = {}
    for i in range(len(edges)):
        if edges[i] in dic.keys():
            dic[edges[i]].append(i+1)
        else:
            dic[edges[i]] = [i+1]

    res = []
    for k in sorted(dic.keys()):
        res += combinations(dic[k])

    return res

def combinations(positions):
    ret = []
    print positions
    for i in range(len(positions)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(positions)):
            ret.append(["e"+str(positions[i]), "e"+str(positions[j])])
    print ret
    return ret

R = [1,3,1,6,9,6,1,2,3,0]
res = extract(R)
print res
```

As we can't see your input, you might encounter problems if there are many combinations. One thing to try is [pypy](http://pypy.org/), which sometimes gives me a (free) speed up.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I understood it the wrong way, the simplest and optimal way to do this is to use a dictionary of already encountered values.

```
elem_dict = {}
output = []
for i, elem in zip (range (length(R))),R):
    if elem_dict.has_key (elem):
        output += [[duplicate, i] for duplicate in elem_dict[elem]]
    else
        elem_dict[elem] = set ()
    elem_dict[elem].add (i)

print output #[[0, 2], [3, 5], [0, 6], [2, 6], [1, 8]]
```

Should be O(n log (n)) in average case, if I'm not mistaken, unless you have a lot of similar values in which case your output is O(n^2) anyway.